# Issue with java client web service REST client. Web service not

Tags: java, web-services

I have a java program that is calling a PHP web service(W/S). The W/S writes a record to a data base table.

When java calls the W/S the record is not written. When I just paste the W/S URL into the browser address bar (from a sys.out), the W/S runs with no problem.

Im receiving a 200 code from Apache after running the client.

This is my first java Rest WS. My code is is below:

```
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import java.net.*;


public class Write2DBWS {

     private static String cid;
     private static String cover;
     private static String corrections;
     private static String url;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        //bucketName     = "claims";
        // keyName        = "cid995/4269-1474672347-allclosingdocuments_ErrorReport.pdf";
        // uploadFileName = "c:/pdf/Pages from 4269-1474672347-allclosingdocuments_ErrorReport.pdf";

        if (args.length == 0) {
            cid = "995";
            cover = "";
            corrections = "cid995/8422-1482271174-estimatingsoftwarearchive_ErrorReport.pdf";
            } else { 

                cid = args[0];
                cover = args[1];
                corrections = args[2];
            }


        Write2DBWS w = new Write2DBWS();

        w.getPlainTextResponse();

    }

         private void getPlainTextResponse() {
         try {

             url = "https://xxxxxxx.com/REST/corrections_acd.php?cid=" + cid + "&handshake=TyServiceToExtractData34985&corrections_src=" + corrections;

             System.out.println(url);        

             Client client = Client.create();

             WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
             ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(" ").get(ClientResponse.class);

             if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                 throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
             }  

             System.out.println("Response => " + response.getStatus());

             //String output2 = response.getEntity(String.class);
             //System.out.println("\n============Plain Text Response============");
             //System.out.println(output2);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }//end of method

    }
```

Comment: there is not enough information to do any kind of troubleshooting - can you at least tell us what errors you are getting?

Comment: Im not receiving any errors. Im actually receiving a apache 200 return code. The DB isnt updated from the java program. But I can plug the url into an address bar and it runs. So I reason it must be in the java code.

Comment: I basically just wanted to know if the W/S is actually running from the java program

Comment: The return code could be 200 but the message returned could be an error (i.e. invalid credentials) - can you inspect the response a bit futher to see what you get?

Comment: Well, it's running... you are getting a response...

Comment: Would I get a 200 code if I had invalid credentials? Seriously, I dont know.

Comment: well, not necessarily invalid credentials - but something not going well in your request (not sure who implemented the WS so there's no telling for sure why you are getting a 200 return code)

Comment: Yes I agree. Im getting a response code. So no telling what's happening. Thank You very much for your pointing me to corrections. Need to drink a beer over it :-)

Comment: The whole issue was I needed to add my W/S to a config file we had here. There was another W/S that does authorization from that config file ... Who knew